# APA7: Skipping maketitle

Tags: apa7

My professor requires me to use a custom title format, but my document errors out when I remove `\maketitle`. The documentation says that maketitle must be the first command after beginning the document.

Here's the desired minimal example:

```latex
\documentclass[stu]{apa7}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
% (some custom title format)
\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All it needed was the header.

```
\documentclass[stu]{apa7}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\@shorttitle{My junk document}% header
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newpage
\raggedright%
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}%
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not quite. The document happily compiles but for some reason, this solution causes paragraphs to begin without indentation. I wouldn't be surprised if there's other less-obvious side effects that I can't immediately see. It looks like maketitle is doing a lot of heavy lifting it shouldn't be

Comment: It was at the very end of `\maketitle`.

Answer (score 1):

I never found a way to remove the maketitle. Instead I just deleted the page it was on using [`atbegshi`](https://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi?lang=en). MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[stu]{apa7}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}}
\title{My junk document}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
% (some custom title format)
\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: If this is for publication, you shouldn't mess with the publisher's format.  Your professor should know this.

Comment: It's not intended to head to a publisher, no. It's somewhere between a course thesis and a research paper, and we're using a departmental format (extended from APA7) that's been used for this course for years. I'm probably the only person in the room who knows what typesetting is, so my professors definitely aren't going to be resources for particularly specific LaTeX questions.