# problem compiling the " \include" in apa7

Tags: include, apa7

Can somebody help me with my code.
Everything was working perfectly until 4 days ago; it does not run anymore. I present a troubleshooting about `\include` .

here my code:

```
\documentclass[table,a4paper,man,floatsintext]{apa7}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx,float}
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable,tabularx,multirow}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{algorithmicx,algpseudocode}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{tikz,nicematrix}
            \usetikzlibrary{calc}    
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X >{$\displaystyle}l<{$}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X >{$\displaystyle}c<{$}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\def\ds{\displaystyle}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sig}{sigm}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cd}{CD}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{77}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{77}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}[section]


\def\gr#1{\text{\bf #1}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rand}{rand}

\newcommand{\bfx}{{\bf x}}
\addbibresource{References1.bib}
\addbibresource{References2.bib}
\addbibresource{References3.bib}


\begin{document}

\include{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\include{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}

\include{dedication}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Dedication}

\include{acknowledge}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgements}


\begin{flushright}
``If everybody was insisted in how we lived and how our country worked,\\
 I think we'd be bringing a lot more light into the world''\\
\emph{Shonda Rhimes}
\end{flushright}

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Contents}
\newpage
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
\newpage
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\include{introduction}
\include{chap2}
\include{chap3}
\include{chap_amopso}
\include{chap_RBF}
\include{chap_vehicule}
\include{conclusion}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\printbibliography
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}

\end{document}
```

I have try to understand where the problem but I can't find any clue.
here the execution lines in pastebin [enter link description here](https://pastebin.com/uGkz6FmV)

Comment: You probably want `\input` instead of `\include`.  `\include` forces a new page.

Comment: I tried but it does not work either

Comment: There is not enough code there to run experiments.  Try a smaller complete MWE and tell us what you don't like about it.

Comment: if I replace \include by \input, it comes to a stop where there is nothing wrong. here the log: https://pastebin.com/Mu6yrAf3

Comment: You need to define `\@shorttitle`.  (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/712796/apa7-skipping-maketitle)